# Expo build error " Cannot find module 'browserslist' " when switching to production mode

Tags: react-native, expo

When I toggle to production mode with Expo Dev Tools, I get the error `Cannot find module 'browserslist'` when I try building my app. [This is the full error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl1SP.png) I get the same error when I toggle to Production Mode with the Expo CLI. Everything works fine when production mode is not enabled.

Comment: do you see the `browserslist` package in your package-lock.json? is it inside of your node_modules? maybe try running `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes, it was in the package-lock.json and inside of the node_modules. For some reason running npm audit fix solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but running `npm audit fix` seemed to solve my issue.